# A slogan of Alain Connes about continuous variables vs discrete.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, functions

I was watching a video of Alain Connes [in french](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLdQqsWPAKI). It's a conference aout Quantum mechanics. And at the begining of the conference  he says that

> "Continuous variables cannot coexist with discret variables"

He defines real variable as a function $f:X\to \Bbb{R},$ nothing about the nature of $X.$

Here is the reason given by Alain Connes in French

"Si $f$ varie continûment l'ensemble $X$ **doit** être non dénombrable. Tout autre variable réelle sur $X$ dont l'image est dénombrable prend alors le même valeur une infinité de fois. Ainsi dans ce formalisme les variables continues ne peuvent coexister avec les variables discrètes."

In English:

> If $f$ varies continuously the set $X$ **must** be uncountable. Any other real variable on $X$ whose image is countable will take the same value an infinity of times. Thus in this formalism, continuous variables cannot coexist with discrete variables.

Can someone explain what it means ? I don't understand why $X$ must be uncountable. There is certainly a tacit assumption about $X$ but I don't see it (otherwise we can take $X$ with the discrete topology for example). The second sentence is as obscure as the first one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that on a probability space $(X,\mathcal A,P)$ two random variables $C$ and $D$ are defined such that $C$ is by definition a continuous random variable and $D$ is a discrete one.

So actually I do not agree or do not correctly understand the first statement.

It is true however that the existence of a continuous random variable on $(X,\mathcal A,P)$ implies uncountability of $X$. In fact a weaker condition is already enough for that: the existence of a random variable on $(X,\mathcal A,P)$ that is *not discrete* (weaker than being continuous) implies that $X$ is uncountable.

This can be rephrased as: if $X$ is countable then random variables defined on $(X,\mathcal A,P)$ are discrete.

For completeness let me mention that the opposite statement is not true. It can happen that *all* random variables defined on $(X,\mathcal A,P)$ are discrete while $X$ is uncountable. To achieve this situation you could do it for instance with $\mathcal A=\{X,\varnothing\}$ where $X$ is uncountable.

Countability of $X$ implies for any random variable $U$ on $(X,\mathcal A,P)$ that the set: $$S:=\{u\in\mathbb R\mid\{U=u\}\neq\varnothing\}$$ is a countable set with $P(U\in S)=1$ and the existence of such a set means exactly that $U$ is a discrete random variable.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Ok si if $U$ is continuous then $X$ is uncountable. Does it follow if $Z$ is another random variable on $X$ whose image is countable will take the same value an infinity of times ?

Comment: Yes. If $Z$ has countable image and $X$ is uncountable then for at least one $z$ belonging to the image of $Z$ the sets $\{Z=z\}:=\{x\in X\mid Z(x)=z\}$ must be uncountable (if not then it can be proved that $X$ is countable as a countable union of countable sets: $X=\bigcup_{z\in I}\{Z=z\}$ where $I$ denotes the image of $Z$).

Comment: thanks a lot, very helpful.

Comment: You are very welcome.